# Why does my Javascript Function stop working after a certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, replace, event-listener

First things first, I'm brand new to Javascript and Regex. I've only been dipping my toes in this past month. I've been trying to put together away to paste a url into a text input then automatically trim it down to just the host name and validate it before I'm able to push the button.

I've gotten it working a few different times but I keep running into the same issue: After a certain period of time, it simply stops working.

I've reformatted and cleaned up the code a few times (though, I'm sure it's still very sloppy because I'm new at this) and I *can* get it working again. But after an hour or so of working, it stops working. Reloading the page doesn't make a difference. Even restarting my computer doesn't make a difference. It simply stops working.

My only guess is that there must be something about the way I'm going about this which is causing it crash or stall out. Perhaps a formatting issue, perhaps the methodology altogether is flawed. I just don't know enough to be able to diagnose it yet.

Hopefully, some of you nice people would be able to point out my flaws or point me in the right direction of how to fix this. I've searched and I couldn't find anyone who was trying to do the things I'm doing all in one build (preparing to myself to be proved wrong here).

Here's the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <input id="notesUrlInput" type="text" placeholder="URL Goes here" pattern="^(?!www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="notesExecuteButton" disabled>Execute</button>
    <span id="notesUrlOutput"></span>
    
    <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      
    <script>


        
        
        
        (function () {
            var timeout = null;
            var notesUrlOutput = document.getElementById("notesUrlOutput");
            var notesExecuteButton = document.getElementById("notesExecuteButton");
            document.getElementById('notesUrlInput').addEventListener('keyup',
                function (e) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = setTimeout(
                    function () {
                        rawInput = $('#notesUrlInput').val();
                            cleanInput = rawInput.replace('www.', '');
                            cleanInput = cleanInput.replace('http://', '');
                            cleanInput = cleanInput.replace('https://', '');
                            cleanInput = cleanInput.replace(/\/.*/,'');
                        $('#notesUrlInput').val(cleanInput);
                        if (cleanInput.value == "") {
                            notesUrlOutput.innerHTML = "";
                            notesExecuteButton.disabled = true; return false;
                        } else if(!notesUrlInput.checkValidity()) {
                            notesUrlOutput.innerHTML = "Invalid URL: Please provide a valid URL";
                            notesExecuteButton.disabled = true; return false;
                        } else {
                            notesUrlOutput.innerHTML = "Input OK";
                            notesExecuteButton.disabled = false; return false;
                        }
                }, 400);
            });
        })();
                    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Frustratingly, when I pasted this code in here and ran it, it worked. As soon as I opened the file I copied this from in my browser. It stopped working. I just don't understand it.

Comment: I did not test the code, but did you try it removing the setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it looks like you want to extract just the domain name from the input field.

You mix JavaScript DOM calls and jQuery, which is fine. It is usually easier to interact with the DOM using just jQuery. Here is your code rewritten in jQuery:

```js
const cleanRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(.*)\/.*$/;
const validRegex = /^[\w\-]+(\.[\w]+)+$/;
(function () {
  $('#notesExecuteButton').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#notesUrlInput').on('input', function(event) {
    let val = $(this).val();
    let cleaned = val.replace(cleanRegex, '$1');
    $(this).val(cleaned);
    if(!cleaned) {
      $('#notesUrlOutput').text('');
      $('#notesExecuteButton').prop('disabled', true);
    } else if(!cleaned.match(validRegex)) {
      $('#notesUrlOutput').text('Invalid URL: Please provide a valid URL');
      $('#notesExecuteButton').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#notesUrlOutput').text('Input OK');
      $('#notesExecuteButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="notesUrlInput" />
<button id="notesExecuteButton" style="disabled: disabled;">Go</button>
<div id="notesUrlOutput"></div>
```

Explanation:

- `.on('input')` - fires every time something changes in the input field- `val.replace(cleanRegex, '$1')` - clean up: strip protocol and `www` prefix, and URL path (any text after domain
- `cleaned.match(validRegex)` - check validity of domain
- `.prop('disabled', true/false)` - add/remove disable property